# How can I enter on the Thank you page in woocommerce the discount code I assigned to the product category?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to show a discount code for each order from the same product category to the user on the "Thank You" page.

```php
if($order->get_total() >= 100000) {
  echo //Discount code 
}
```

Comment: There are a few hooks available on order received page. You can use any of them to display your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the code for the Thank You page [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html).  May I suggest the [`woocommerce_thankyou`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html#source-view.79) hook?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is good content.

Comment: You're welcome @payam-mohammadi.  Mind upvoting my answer if you liked it?  And if this solved your problem, please kindly mark my answer as correct.